# Incident ID per Year

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to get an automated incrementing case number by year going. I was able to get it with the following code.

```
create function CalcIncidentID(@yrIn int)
returns float
as 
-------------------------------------
--* This function calculates the next case # for a year
--* Usage:
--*       Select CalcIncidentID(2012)
------------------------------------------

begin
    Declare @nextCase as int;
    Declare @nextYear as int;

    SET @nextYear = (@yrin +1) *10000
    SET @yrIn = (@yrIn*10000)

    SET @nextCase = (Select MAX(IncidentID)
                        From Incident
                        Where IncidentID > @yrin and IncidentID <= @nextYear) + 1

    if @nextCase is null
        SET @nextCase = @yrIn+1

    return @nextCase
end
```

Though this works fine I would like to get this to have the following format (YYYY-####) rather than the current (YYYY####).

I know it will have to return as varchar. Though I can't figure out how to set the next case if IncidentID isn't one number.

Comment: Why `returns float`? I see only int arithmetic.

Comment: TBH I'm not sure. That is just what my professor suggested I do.

Comment: What do you mean by `if IncidentID isn't one number`? Sample data, current results, and desired results would all be helpful. Good tips & tools here to help you improve your question and make it easier for us to help you. [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)